# Running tests in single Python file with nose

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I'm using nose 1.3.7 with Anaconda 4.1.1 (Python 3.5.2). I want to run unit tests in a single file, e.g. `foo.py`. According to the [documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) I should be able to simply run:

```
nosetests foo.py
```

But when I do this, nose runs all the tests in all the files in the directory!

And if I do `nose --help`, the usage documentation doesn't even indicate that there is a  parameter. It only shows [options].

So can I run tests in a single file using nose?

Answer (score 1):

I have a standalone Python 3.4 version and `nosetests foo.py`  runs tests only in `foo.py` and `nosetests spam.py` runs test only in `spam.py`.

A plain `nosetests` command without any option specified, runs tests in all files with names starting with the word `test_` in the directory.

Here's quoting from their [test discovery](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/finding_tests.html) documentation which specifies rules for test discovery.The last line of the documentation clarifies what could be the cause for your anomaly.

> Be aware that plugins and command line options can change any of those
>   rules.

I suspect (and I may be wrong) that it has to do with how anaconda configures nose for your install.

Answer (score 0):

Be also sure you don't have `nose.run()` or `nose.main()` inside the file to be tested.